# Where are all past Salesforce Release Notes

Tags: apex, notes, release

As a follow on to the recently posted question 
"[What are all of the reasons why Salesforce customers should upgrade the API version on their Apex classes, triggers, and pages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40019/what-are-all-of-the-reasons-why-salesforce-customers-should-upgrade-the-api-vers)".

Where can I find all past Salesforce Release Notes, so I can review changes necessary to upgrade my Apex classes, triggers and pages to newer API versions?

I need notes all the way back as far as v18.0, other people may need to go back even further.

Going to https://developer.salesforce.com/releases, currently shows Summer '14 Release Preview. There is a link there to "Past Release: Spring '14" but that doesn't go anywhere and there is no link to all past releases that I can find.

Comment: I just spent like 10 minutes searching for it, and I just couldn't find it! I could have sworn there was a page that listed them all out, but the best I could find is http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_welcome_release_notes.htm which only has the past 3.

Comment: Here are all Earlier Reference Docs https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Earlier_Reference_Documentation. However, these do not include Release Notes, ideally they would be listed here as well.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

- [image] Winter '24 (v59.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/246/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter24_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Summer '23 Lifeguard Ruth] Summer '23 (v58.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/244/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer23_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Spring '23 Codey building a birdhouse] Spring '23 (v57.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/242/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring23_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Winter '23 Brandy with Snowboard] Winter '23 (v56.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/240/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter23_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Summer '22 Einstein on water skis] Summer '22 (v55.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/238/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer22_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Spring '22 Ruth with Fruit] Spring '22 (v54.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/236/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring22_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Winter '22 Yeti Astro with heart flag] Winter '22 (v53.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/234/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter22_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Summer '21 Cloudy with heart] Summer '21 (v52.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/232/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer21_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Spring '21 Codey with heart] Spring '21 (v51.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/230/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring21_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Yeti Astro with heart]Winter '21 (v50.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/228/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter21_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Trailheart Astro]Summer '20 (v49.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/226/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer20_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Blaze]Spring '20 (v48.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/224/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring20_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Astro Chilling on the Beach]Winter '20 (v47.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/222/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter20_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Paddleboarding Codey] Summer '19 (v46.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/220/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer19_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Einstein] Spring '19 (v45.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/218/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring19_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Snowboarding Astro] Winter '19 (v44.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter19_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Snorkel Codey] Summer '18 (v43.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer18_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Bonsai] Spring '18 (v42.0) https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/212/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring18_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Yeti Astro] Winter '18 (v41.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter18_release_notes.pdf

---

- [image: Seagulls] Summer '17 (v40.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer17_release_notes.pdf
- [image: Rainbow] Spring '17 (v39.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring17_release_notes.pdf
- [image: Snowman] Winter '17 (v38.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter17_release_notes.pdf
- [image: Fireworks] Summer
  '16 (v37.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer16_release_notes.pdf
- [image] Spring '16 (v36.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring16_release_notes.pdf
- [image] Winter '16 (v35.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter16_release_notes.pdf

- [image] Summer '15 (v34.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/196/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer15_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '15 (v33.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring15_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '15 (v32.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/192/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '14 (v31.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/190/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer14_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '14 (v30.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/188/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '14 (v29.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/186/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '13 (v28.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/184/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '13 (v27.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/182/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring13_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '13 (v26.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/180/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter13_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '12 (v25.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/178/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer12_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '12 (v24.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/176/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring12_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '12 (v23.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/174/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter12_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '11 (v22.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/172/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer11_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '11 (v21.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/170/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring11_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '11 (v20.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/168/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter11_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '10 (v19.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/166/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer10_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '10 (v18.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/164/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring10_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '10 (v17.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/162/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter10_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '09 (v16.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/160/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer09_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '09 (v15.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/158/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring09_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '09 (v14.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/156/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter09_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '08 (v13.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/154/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer08_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '08 (v12.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/152/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring08_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '08 (v11.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/150/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter08_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '07 (v10.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/148/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer07_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '07 (v9.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/146/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring07_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '07 (v8.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/144/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter07_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '06 (v7.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer06_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '06 (v6.0) **Not released**
- Winter '06 (v5.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter06_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '05 (v4.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer05_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '05 (v3.0) **Not released**
- Winter '05 (v2.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter05_release_notes.pdf

- Summer '04 (v1.0) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer04_release_notes.pdf
- Spring '04 (v?.?) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring04_release_notes.pdf
- Winter '04 (v?.?) http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/142/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter04_release_notes.pdf

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=whats_new.htm&language=en_US

**Not Released**

> It turns out that *Spring '05* and *Spring '06* were not released. Hence--no release notes!
>
> - https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs/status/695308101667414016

## Matching Releases to API versions

You can use `/services/data/` to get XML that links from the release name to the API version from Winter '11 onward. [[Source]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/68343/102)

[image: Linking API version to Release name]

Comment: That's one way of doing it! Upvoted!

Comment: This answer shows dedication, well done!

Comment: Really good answer ! Upvoted too

Comment: Why release notes pdf link is not working? I tried winter 15 release notes.

Comment: If anyone gets a chance to update this, some logos going back to 2004 can be found here: https://sfdcmonkey.com/salesforce-release-logo-journey/

Answer (score 6):

You can always find the list here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=whats_new.htm&language=en_US

Should the link change in future searching for "past releases" should find it.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer has all the links and it should be upvoted but isn't it easy to go to developer.force.com and search for release notes.

You can check using the below link: https://developer.salesforce.com/search?q=release%20notes&language=en