# 6 minute delay in a Visualforce response in Spring ‘20 Sandbox Preview orgs

Tags: apex, visualforce, timeout, spring-20

We have **one** managed package Visualforce UI `<apex:commandButton .../>` timing out **only in** Spring ‘20 Sandbox Preview orgs. The tail end of the log looks like this:

```
11:42:28.5 (1587639757)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this|{}|0x13e6c054
11:42:28.5 (1587652325)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[80]
11:42:28.5 (1587655972)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[81]
11:42:28.5 (1587658790)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[84]
11:42:28.5 (1587717838)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1084]|Bytes:5
11:42:28.5 (1587726691)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:42:28.5 (1587735431)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1084]|Bytes:5
11:42:28.5 (1592110360)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|0663k000002asoA
11:42:28.5 (1614323990)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
11:48:59.879 (392879638294)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
11:48:59.879 (392879638294)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 461 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:48:59.879 (392879638294)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|cve|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 1 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:48:59.879 (392879638294)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:48:59.879 (392879825168)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/cve__claimintakewizardbenefitstep
11:48:59.879 (392881965050)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

i.e. a 6 minute+ delay after VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END (marked with XXX above). As can be seen from the limit usage there is no DML, so database locking seems unlikely. All other `<apex:commandButton .../>` cases are working fine so far.

Are others experiencing this sort of problem? I couldn't find anything via Google.

**PS**

I've just created a Salesforce support case on this #25293687.

**PPS**

Slow progress with support, but just having retested in one of the problem orgs, **the problem is no longer happening**. We have changed nothing, so perhaps Salesforce have. When my colleagues have checked a couple more orgs, I'll close this (and the support case) down.

Comment: Hey, Keith, I would look more carefully at the following Critical Updates and possibly test disabling them: "Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema", "Require Customize Application permission for direct read access to custom metadata types", "Require Customize Application permission for direct read access to custom settings", "Disable Access to Non-global Controller Methods in Managed Packages", and "Restrict Reflective Access to Non-Global Controller Constructors in Packages".

Comment: Do you know what query it is running? Any chance it could be against a large data volume?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, Yes it is a single `StaticResource` row query with plenty of Apex code having executed afterward. I just added a PPS to the question to say it looks like the problem has gone away so this is likely to remain a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of around 6 pm today, the problem is no longer happening in 3 different preview orgs. We haven't changed our code, so something has changed on the Salesforce side to fix this. Good news.

Perhaps such problems are to be expected in a preview rather than GA version of the platform.

Comment: `Perhaps such problems are to be expected in a preview` - the story of my life in preview orgs - stuff fails, you spend all day debugging and then 24 hrs later, the problem goes away

Comment: I asked [How can I tell what is changing in Salesforce as they patch each pod?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/80546/102) as a way to try and figure out sudden changes in observed behavior.