# API version changelog

Tags: api

Does such a thing exist?

For example, I'm trying to figure out which API version the "40 character limit on pick-lists" was relaxed.

Comment: I think I have effectively answered the question posed here since you posted another one more specific to your struggles?

Comment: yea, I was hoping someone would have a better resource but I fear I have to accept one does not exists...

Comment: There is a compendium of Release Notes on this exchange... Perhaps relevant/duplicate? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40411/where-are-all-past-salesforce-release-notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hasn't been updated since July 2014, but [Earlier Reference Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Earlier_Reference_Documentation) has a lot of the former documentation in one place for your reference. As far as I know, there is no centralized repository where you could search to figure out the type of information you are looking for.

Might as well mention, the [Ideas Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) and [Known Issues Log](https://success.salesforce.com/issues) are great places to go looking if you're not sure where to start. Specifically there is relevant information on [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KSkNAAW).

Comment: jesus... it would be nice if they at least kept notes for changes from 1 version to the next.  Instead you have to browse the entire developer guide and find differences?  I wonder what would have happen if you ran these documents through a difftool