# How/Where can I get the Salesforce API versions 42 to 49 exact release dates?

Tags: lightning, community

I tried to find the release dates of Salesforce API versions 42 to 49 but didn't get any.
Can anyone provide me with the dates for the Salesforce API v42 to v49? Or redirect me to Salesforce doc where it is maintained?

PS: I only need release dates for the mentioned versions not release notes.

Comment: you can check status.salesforce.com, you'll get all history release/maintenance dates

Comment: It's too vague to identify from this one. Can you please redirect me for the one specific version.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer can possibly help you: [reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/40419)

As per its naming convention Summer '20 (latest), Spring '20 and so on, Salesforce seems to begin its primary release when Summer begins, and then adds features/fixes throughout the Summer.

If you open the above answer link, and open the PDFs. Open the Release Notes section and scroll all the way down to last release note. That will be the beginning of the initial release of Summer '20.

Whether you want final stable release date or primary release date, you can extract as per your use case.

[EDIT] For eg: If you want the release date for Summer '20 release, final stable release date is July 8, 2020 (and it may continue as until Summer ends) and primary release date is May 4, 2020.

Comment: Thanks but I already went through the one of pdfs but not able to get the release date.
And I want primary/first release date.

Comment: Open any PDF in the link above, search for "Your Feedback Matters", scroll up, and you'll find your primary release date.

Answer (score 6):

I went through the efforts of seeing all the PDFs, and here are the *primary* release dates for each version you have asked for:

1. v49.0: May 4, 2020
2. v48.0: December 16, 2019
3. v47.0: August 19, 2019
4. v46.0: April 22, 2019
5. v45.0: December 17, 2018
6. v44.0: August 20, 2018
7. v43.0: April 23, 2018
8. v42.0: December 18, 2017

Comment: What does "primary release date" mean? That is not a concept Salesforce uses.

Comment: Primary release date means when Salesforce began release of the said version. I understand it isn't a SF term.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. +1 for the work you put into this.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce API versions are released with major seasonal releases of Salesforce, such as Winter '20, Spring '21, and so on. Each major release rolls out over several months in multiple phases, starting with preview instances, then selected sandboxes instances, and continuing through multiple waves of rollout to different subsets of production instances.

There is no single release date for any API version. It's always an extended process. The concept of a release date simply isn't very meaningful for Salesforce API versions.

As another answerer has already advised, you can get information about the release history and future schedule of *your Salesforce org* from `trust.salesforce.com` by searching for the instance your org is on (found in Setup->Company Information) and clicking Maintenance. But again, looking backwards at this information provides little useful insight or value beyond answering specific questions about the revision history of your org, and it will differ from the history of orgs on other instances.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to the above answers,
I have found, One can always find it online through the link:
[https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/{version}/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm#rn_change_log](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/%7Bversion%7D/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm#rn_change_log).

For example, If someone wants someone the release notes & dates for the Spirng19 then just replace version with spring19 as mentioned: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm#rn_change_log

For Summer20: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm#rn_change_log

Thanks