# getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() Doesn't Return All Fields: Bug or Expected Behavior?

Tags: apex, bug, summer-16

I was very excited to learn about the new getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() method added to the SObject class with Summer '16. Unfortunately upon testing I found what *appears* to be a bug based on my understanding. The method is intended to allow developers to easily obtain fields populated in memory. According to the docs:

> A field is populated in memory in the following cases.
>
> - The field has been queried by a SOQL statement.
> - The field has been explicitly set before the call to the getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() method.

In practice, I've found that if a field is not included in a SOQL query when retrieving an existing record it will be excluded from the field map returned by the new method, even if it was explicitly set before the call:

```
Contact c = [SELECT Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
c.Title = 'President';
Map<String,Object> fieldsMap = c.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
System.debug(fieldsMap);
// DEBUG|{Id=003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Name=Jack Rogers}
// Note: Title field is not returned
```

However, a field explicitly set before the call *is* included in the case of a new SObject instance:

```
Contact c = new Contact();
c.Title = 'President';
Map<String,Object> fieldsMap = c.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
System.debug(fieldsMap);
// DEBUG|{Title=President}
```

Here is a [gist](http://bit.ly/29crdO6) that can be run in the dev console to see first hand what I'm experiencing. AFAICT this seems like a bug, but I'm curious to hear if others see it as expected behavior.

[@AndyFawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) has kindly opened a case with Salesforce developer support-I will update this post with their response once we know more.

Comment: For reference: [Corresponding Twitter conversation that preceded Q](https://twitter.com/scottbcovert/status/750395061561495552)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apex dev team saw Andy's case and the resulting discussion and logged bug [W-3223800](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkyG) for this. The behavior you're seeing is a bug.

The fix is scheduled for Spring 17, although safeharbor as always. Also, I've been informed it will be a versioned change, so **be sure to update the API version of your apex classes to v39.0 or later**.

[Maps of Populated SObject Fields Return Correct Values](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_map.htm)

Comment: I still got issue now with version API -46 .