# Why do Apex classes have an API version

Tags: apex, api-version

I am unsure why each class has an API version. I know during each release they have added functionality therefore previous versions would not support this but I feel there must be more of a reason.

I also assume API versions is how they deprecate things and add new functionality. Is it best practice to update a class to the newest API if it has no dependencies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put it simply: The API version decides a couple of things for the Apex class - what fields you can access on a particular object or how you can implement certain mechanics.

And you're correct - API versions are used to introduce new features as well as deprecate old ones. Think of it as a way to decide what collection of functionality you want to use.

What is the best practice is an entirely different question - but to give you a very basic idea for this: Different API versions *can* give you all kinds of weird errors and behavior. From my personal experience, it is best to upgrade your API versions from time to time, so you have a consistent and recent version over all your classes and throughout your org.

See also:
[What are all of the reasons why Salesforce customers should upgrade the API version on their Apex classes, triggers, and pages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40019/what-are-all-of-the-reasons-why-salesforce-customers-should-upgrade-the-api-vers)