# Apex classes - benefits of updating to the newer version

Tags: apex

This is related to Apex API version, where Salesforce releases New versions.

Is there any benefit of changing the current old API version of Apex class to the new API version?
Does changing the version affect the functionality of Apex class?

Is there any documentation or best practices for the Apex API version. Please comment thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API versions are used to introduce new features as well as deprecate old ones. If you want to be able to safely leverage SFDC's latest features you should be periodically updating the [API version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_intro.htm) ideally with each release.

Also check [Why do Apex classes have an API version](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232081/why-do-apex-classes-have-an-api-version).

Thanks,